# How to know if telnet stream is at await state or not from looking at the logs

Tags: telnet, logger

I have started a telnet session and it prints the output to a file and i give commands to the telnet after analyzing the log file log.txt. Below is the bash code

```
cat my1.fifo | telnet 172.27.172.150 10022 | tee -a log.txt &
```

the telnet session logs the output to the file but it is difficult when telnet doesn't add a newline after printing the line. For example during login : await state there is no end of line character so it is difficult to know when exactly the line ended and should i go ahead to read it or not because only after reading the last line of log.txt i am going to decide what to feed to telnet through the my1.fifo file.

Comment: That's not how `telnet` works. You'll have to use `expect`. Read `man telnet expect`.